# É uma boa prática manter colunas de chave estrangeira redundantes?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional, chave-estrangeira

Considere que temos os modelos `A`, `B`, `C` e `D`, cada um referenciando para o anterior, ou seja, `A` tem muitos `B`s, `B` tem muitos `C`s e `C` tem muitos `D`s:

### Sem redundância

```
A
|  id | ... |
------------
| ... | ... |

B
|  id | a_id | ... |
--------------------
| ... |  ... | ... |

C
|  id | b_id | ... |
--------------------
| ... |  ... | ... |

D
|  id | c_id | ... |
--------------------
| ... |  ... | ... |
```

---

Seria recomendado incluir mais colunas em `C` e `D` indicando qual o registro referenciado de `A` e `B`?

### Com redundância

```
C
|  id | a_id | b_id | ... |
---------------------------
| ... |  ... |  ... | ... |

D
|  id | a_id | b_id | c_id | ... |
----------------------------------
| ... |  ... |  ... |  ... | ... |
```

É uma redundância, mas eu costumo fazer isso para facilitar as consultas, é útil para evitar `JOIN`s. Também acredito que a economia de `JOIN`s melhore o desempenho.

Isso é considerado boa ou má prática? (Se não em todos os casos, pelo menos quando os dados são imutáveis) Existe alguma solução melhor para isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Você não pediu a opinião pessoal, perguntou se era uma boa prática. Além disso O StackOverflow não se propõe a responder perguntar baseadas em opinião pessoal e recomenda que não se façam perguntas deste tipo e muito menos que sejam dadas respostas baseadas em opiniões pessoais.
2. Não, não é uma boa prática. É realmente uma péssima prática. Não é uma opinião pessoal veja os pontos abaixo. Além disso se quiser opiniões pessoais faça esse tipo de pergunta em forums especializados como o SQL Server Central (e prepare-se para possíveis respostas "duras")
3. Não é nem uma questão de DRY mas de normalização mesmo. Devemos desnormalizar apenas quando estritamente necessário (para desempenho). Esses são casos raros.
4. Você vai apenas escrever menos joins, não necessariamente o SGBD vai conseguir te dar mais desempenho. Ao contrário pode piorar pois na medida que você inclui dados redundantes e usa índices você também vai ocupar mais espaço na HD (mais IO), forçar mais uso de CPU e memória.
5. Geralmente não importa o número de joins. Se você indexou bem e normalizou corretamente você já deve conseguir um bom desempenho.
6. Se você tiver uma massa de dados muito grande e relacionamentos complexos há outros meios muito melhores de conseguir desempenho como usar views, particionar tabelas, tunning fino de índices, etc

Comment: Ok, você venceu :-P Quando eu escrevi aquela resposta não tinha opinião totalmente formada. Hoje já concordo com você.

Answer (score 6):

Minha opinião pessoal é que o benefício não compensa o efeito em cascata das atualizações e validações de integridade em uma grande massa de dados.

- Vários DBMSs implementam planos de execução onde a dependência entre estruturas é levada em consideração. Aumentando a complexidade dos relacionamentos descritos pelas chaves estrangeiras, você pode estar prejudicando a avaliação deste plano;
- Se você excluir ou modificar um item da tabela **A**, ainda assim todos os registros dependentes de **B**, **C** e **D** precisarão ser validados para fins de consistência. O modelo proposto não oferece nenhum benefício para operações de alteração de dados (`UPDATE` / `DELETE`).
- Caso você altere o tipo de `A.ID`, você precisará realizar alterações em todas as tabelas, e não apenas no tipo de `B.A_ID`.
- Várias ferramentas de ORM dependem de uma representação correta da interdependência entre tabelas na base de dados.

Se sua única vantagem que desta implementação é a agilidade para a criação de *queries*, eu faria o esforço extra de descrever corretamente o interrelacionamento.

(Adicionalmente, existe um princípio de desenvolvimento de sistemas chamado **'[não se repita](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)'** (do inglês *Don't repeat yourself*), que alguns DBAs também se utilizam por considerar a prática como uma boa escolha para higiene de dados.)

Comment: Não coloquei na pergunta, mas... E se os dados forem imutáveis?

Comment: @Andrey Para dizer a verdade, eu levei em consideraçao que todos os campos mencionados eram imutáveis. Estritamente falando, neste caso a parte do segundo tópico mencionando uma operação de UPDATE possa talvez ser descartada - imagino que a maioria dos DBMSs só testem cardinalidade se os campos envolvidos em um relacionamento forem alterados - mas ainda assim todos os outros pontos são válidos.