# Dúvida com modelagem relacional

Tags: mysql, sql, modelo-relacional

Estou montando um cadastro de imóveis, aonde estes imóveis pertencem a um endereço, que pertence a um bairro que pertence a uma cidade.

Ex tabelas:

```
Imoveis: id, endereco_id, etc...

Enderecos: id, nome, bairro_id, rua, numero, cep, etc...

Bairros: id, nome, cidade_id

Cidades: id, nome;
```

Porém, se eu quiser efetuar uma busca de imóveis em uma cidade cadastrada, como fica este relacionamento, é válido duplicar a chave dentro de Imoveis, criando uma cidade_id?

Primeira situação: Ao efetuar buscas em selects, quero listar apenas as cidades que possuem imóveis cadastrados.

Segunda situação: Selecionar a cidade e listar via ajax os bairros que possuem cadastro de imovel.

Terceira situação: buscar os imóveis e listar juntamente com eles, os respectivos enderecos, bairro e cidade.

Alguma idéia de como trabalhar melhor estes dados, e se estou no caminho certo?

Obs: Não estou pedindo as queries prontas, e sim idéias de como implementar da melhor forma este modelo relacional, aonde o cadastro de cada bairro e cidade será feito juntamente com as outras informações do imóvel, salvando de forma consistente os nomes de bairros e cidades, evitando a duplicidade do cadastro destes.

Comment: Minha primeira dúvida seria se você realmente precisa ter esta normalização do endereço. Tem alguma necessidade ou vantagem? Um imóvel pode estar em mais de um endereço? Existe uma razão para o endereço estar separado?

Comment: Em relação a redundância dos `id`s, talvez te interesse: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22208/7261 Você pode optar por ter uma coluna `[tabela]_id` redundante ou usar `JOIN` para fazer a consulta filtrando por cidade. Na segunda situação, pode usar um `LEFT JOIN` ou `RIGHT JOIN`

Comment: @bigown Um imóvel pertence a um endereço único. Está separado, porque a tabela imóvel é grande, e porque nem sempre vou chamar Endereços...Existe a questão da atualização em cascata, se remover uma cidade, ou bairro, deve ir tudo o que pertence a ele/ela junto.

Comment: @Marcelo (apenas um comentário...) para isso bastaria selecionar os campos que for usar no select, não precisaria necessariamente separar a tabela.

Comment: Mas para efeito de desempenho, quanto menor a tabela, não há melhor desempenho em `selects`?

Comment: @MarceloAymone Você tentou das duas formas e mediu se há ganho? Ter que acessar dados em dois lugares piora a performance. Se a tabela é menor **pode** ter ganho de performance. Mas só se todos dados estão nela. Separar pode até organizar um pouco mais, só isto. Mas é raro precisar de toda esta organização.

Comment: @MarceloAymone o que vai dar o desempenho é índice, e a quantidade de dados que trafega pela interface. Pode até haver diferença em separação de arquivos dependendo da forma que você organiza (para melhor ou pior inclusive), mas para se preocupar com esse tipo de ajuste, só numa aplicação imensa ou muito crítica (envolveria uma análise mais complexa do caso).

Comment: Ok, na verdade, separar ou não endereco não seria o meu foco da pergunta e sim quanto a cidades e bairros, etc.

Comment: Não respondi porque você já obteve uma resposta. Exceto pelo endereço separado, sua modelagem está boa, é só fazer as *queries* corretamente. Na resposta tem uma boa base para fazer. Cidade e Bairro são entidades e não uma descrição, portanto você fez o correto. Aí você vai ter que ver se vai implementar alguma forma de achar bairros próximos em um raio. É bem mais complicado mas é muito útil e muitos sites do tipo implementam isto. Foi só uma ideia para você.

Comment: Havia pensado nisto @bigown, realmente é algo bem interessante buscar por proximidade. Permite ao usuário mais dinamicidade de busca, vou condensar imovel e endereco na mesma tabela e tentar seguir com bairro e cidade como entidades.

Comment: @MarceloAymone até por serem realmente entidades. Melhor cadastrar o bairro novo quando precisar, do que virar bagunça. Um lembrete: bairro é entidade de cidade, e não do cadastro geral. Isso facilita mais ainda a organização. Mesmo que dois bairros tenham nomes iguais em cidades diferentes (ou o Centro, por exemplo), tratando separadamente é conceitualmente melhor. "coincidência" não deve ser convertida em regra ;)

Comment: Vale uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/622/qual-a-melhor-maneira-de-se-representar-um-endere%C3%A7o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo comentários e aspectos expostos na pergunta, a melhor maneira de modelar suas tabelas é a seguinte:

- **Imoveis**: id, nome, cidade_id, rua, numero, complemento, cep, bairro, ...
- **Cidades**: id, nome, *estado*, ...

O estado colocado em `Cidades` pode ser uma tabela `Estado` ou então um enumerável dentro da sua aplicação, se a aplicação funcionar apenas para o Brasil.

Podemos juntar `Enderecos` e `Imoveis` dentro de uma única tabela, visto que a cardinalidade sempre será de 1 pra 1 entre essas duas tabelas, e a manutenção de dois objetos pode causar inconsistências desnecessárias.

Um cadastro de bairros pode ser interessante se forem poucas cidades, mas se torna trabalhoso considerando que seu sistema pode trabalhar com o país inteiro. Por exemplo, para cadastrar um imóvel, o bairro teria que existir primeiro. Não apenas isso, em cidades como São Paulo, não há concordância com o nome do bairro em determinadas regiões. Já vi cadastros em que um endereço aparece em até 3 bairros diferentes.

Portanto, o melhor para `Bairros` é utilizar uma coluna `bairro`, em que o nome do bairro possa ser especificado por extenso.

Para `Cidades`, o melhor é `Imoveis` referenciá-la diretamente. Você conseguirá sua pesquisa por cidade facilmente desta forma. Voltando ao problema dos bairros, o `join` para a pesquisa seria maior e mais complexo, além de ter o agravante do problema de dissonância entre bairros de uma mesma cidade, conforme expliquei mais acima:

```
select c.*, b.*, i.*
from Imoveis i
inner join Bairros b on i.bairro_id = b.id
inner join Cidades c on b.cidade_id = c.id
where c.nome like "%expressao%";
```

Da forma sugerida na resposta, fica:

```
select c.*, i.*
from Imoveis i
inner join Cidades c on i.cidade_id = c.id
where c.nome like "%expressao%";
```

Comment: Estado não tem necessidade, o foco da aplicação é apenas no estado de santa catarina, com foco na região da capital e adjacentes.

Comment: Melhor ainda. O campo pode ser retirado da modelagem, então.

Comment: Considerando que vou necessitar fazer uma busca de imóveis cadastrados em um determinado bairro de uma determinada cidade, e que gostaria que apenas cidades e bairros com imóveis cadastrados apareçam nesta lista, permitindo que se cadastre manualmente o bairro, como evitar duplicidade em casos de um nome de bairro mal digitado?
Eu estava pensando em fazer um botão "Adicionar bairro/cidade" em que pudesse ser salvo via ajax um novo bairro, e recarregado automaticamente no select para o usuário incluir um bairro/cidade que não existe ainda no sgbd

Comment: A maneira mais legal de fazer isso seria gravando o nome do bairro fonetizado. Por exemplo, se o usuário escrever "Cerqueira Cézar", "Cerqueira Cesar" ou então "Cerqueira César", o algoritmo fonetizaria uma única `String` para os três, evitando esses problemas de cadastro. Na pesquisa, pesquisando por qualquer uma das `Strings` de exemplo retornaria todos os resultados. [Veja esta questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1828/como-fazer-um-algoritmo-fon%C3%A9tico-para-o-portugu%C3%AAs-brasileiro) em que isso é tratado com mais detalhes.

Comment: Achei interessante, mas um canhão para matar moscas.
É somente um site de imobiliária com buscas por cidades, bairros, quartos, etc.

Comment: Não é tão difícil quanto parece. [Veja este outro link](http://sourceforge.net/p/metaphoneptbr/code/ci/master/tree/README).

Comment: Não pela dificuldade, o negócio do site é vender imóveis, não cadastrar com a máxima eficiência, até porque, o cadastro será pela própria imobiliária, reduzindo significativamente a chance de erro, pensei até em utilizar um webservice como busca cep, por ser mais simples, quanto a minha dúvida de normalizar ou não, as cidades e bairros, seria mais com foco de facilitar a pesquisa através de detalhes como estes.

Comment: Bom, isto possivelmente é escopo para outra pergunta ;)